# Can I build .NET Core 3.1 application in VS 2019 and run with mono on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mono

I know that .net core is available for Linux, I can build in VS 2019 and publish for Linux, including self-contained package. So that is all beautiful and there would be no issue, unless... We have a customer using RHEL 7.1 little-endian on Power8 CPU where there is Mono 6.8. No dotnet on any PowerPC platform, as far we can see (havent got access to test machine yet). So we need to investigate if the project written in .NET Core 3.1 could be ported to Mono.

As first step to test the porting path, I create simple command line app that basically prints "Hello" and exits. Then I build Any CPU and install Mono 6.12 on Windows, try to run:

```
> mono Simple.Dll
  Hello!
```

So it worked also with Mono on Windows, and of course with dotnet. Now, build and deploy using RID `linux-x64` to the Ubuntu 20.04 running on Windows subsystem for Linux.

[image]

Having dotnet installed for Ubuntu, it works fine, both when I use 'Portable' or `linux-x64` in deploy:

```
> dotnet Simple.dll
  Hello!
```

Then I install mono:

```
> sudo apt install mono-runtime 
> ...
> mono --version
    Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (Debian 6.8.0.105+dfsg-2 Wed Feb 26 23:23:50 UTC 2020)
> dotnet --version
    3.1.402
```

The next obvious step:

```
> mono Simple.dll
  "The entry point method could not be loaded due to Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies."
```

The same (with Version=4.2.1.0) error happens when I try to downgrade to .NET 2.1. So this is where my understanding of CLI world reaches its limit. Am I missing part of runtime libraries on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The `dotnet publish` generated binaries are strictly for .NET Core, and only supported on a few platforms,

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1-supported-os.md

If you do need to support more platforms, then

- Port .NET Core runtime to that platform. You can see that there are community efforts out there (like [the FreeBSD port](https://github.com/jasonpugsley/installer/wiki/.NET-5.0-Preview-3-for-FreeBSD)).
- Share the source code between a .NET Core project and a .NET Framework/Mono project, so that you can generate Mono compatible binaries in parallel.

Comment: So my Simple.dll worked on Windows mono because it actually used System.Runtime from the dotnet ?